# Replace number in string with divided value?

Tags: php

Is there a way in php (maybe with regex or preg_replace) to find every number in a string and then divide it by two? Let's say the string is like this:

```
John has 20 apples and Maria has 100 pears.
```

This would then be converted to

```
John has 10 apples and Maria has 50 pears.
```

I'm not really sure how to pass the variables of the replacement in preg_replace and this is what I've done but any php mind can see that this is not working:

```
$output = preg_replace("([0-9]+)", "\$1"/2, $string);
```

Comment: http://php.net/preg_replace_callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code with `preg_replace_callback()`. This will give you the expected result.

```
<?php
$string = "John has 20 apples and Maria has 100 pears.";
$output = preg_replace_callback(
        "([0-9]+)",
        function ($matches) {
            return ($matches[0]/2);
        },
        $string
    );
echo "Result : ".$output;
?>
```

**Output**

```
Result : John has 10 apples and Maria has 50 pears.
```